# The surface of the cylinder as a differentiable manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

Consider the surface K of the cylinder with radius 1 and height 1 and let $B_1 , B_2$ be its bases. Then $K-(B_1 \cup B_2)$ is a 2-dimensional differentiable manifold.

I get that $K-(B_1 \cup B_2) = S^{1}\times(0,1) $ but what are the considered maximal atlas of each manifold?

Comment: The maximal atlas of a manifold is never explicitly known: it is a way too large set. We just have to exhibit a (preferably finite) particular atlas, and the theory ensures that there is a unique maximal compatible atlas.

Comment: @Didier ok, so we consider a maximal atlas A of $S^{1}$, a maximal atlas B of (0,1), so the cylinder is a manifold with maximal atlas the maximal atlas that contains $A \times B$?

Comment: This works, yes (no need to take maximal atlases for $A$ and $B$ though)